# modules, function scope, and jQuery noConflict() issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, browserify, node-modules

**Setup**

I have a script that loads jQuery using noConflict(true) on pages that might already have an older version of jQuery on it.  My script is built in node using modules and packaged into a single file using browserify.

**Issue**

I'm having trouble properly scoping my functions from other modules to preserve the variable $ set up through noConflict().  For example imagine a site already has loaded jQuery version 1.8, and my script is loaded on the page and loads jQuery v. 3.2

```html
<!-- Client site loads old version of jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<!-- Our script loads via ajax as a self executing anonymous function.
Just using this scrip tag as an example -->
<script src="myScript.js"></script>
```

```js
// Contents of myScript.js is bundled with Browserify and hosted
//on our server.  Here is the pre-Browserify code: 

var otherModule = require('./funcB')

//check version of jQuery and load newer version if necessary
if ((typeof jQuery === 'undefined') || (parseFloat(jQuery.fn.jquery) < 3.0)) {
  //loadScript (not shown) is just a function that adds a script tag via
  //ajax to the site <head>
  loadScript("https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js", function(){
      jQuery321 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
      funcA(jQuery321);
  });
  } else {
      funcA(jQuery);
}

var funcA = function($){ 
    $('document').ready(function(){
    
      console.log('jquery in funcA: v' + $.fn.jquery)  
      //outputs:  "jquery in funcA: v3.2.1"
      otherModule.funcB();  
      //outputs: "jquery in funcB: v1.8.1"
      funcC();  
      //outputs: "jquery in funcB: v3.2.1"
      
    })
    
    function funcC(){
      console.log('jquery in funcC: v' + $.fn.jquery)
    }  
}
```

```js
//code from otherModule --> funcB.js 

exports.funcB = function(){
  console.log("jQuery in funcB: v" + $.fn.jquery)
}

module.exports = exports;
```

**The Question**
Obviously this is working as expected, however is there a way to preserve $ as a reference to jQuery v3.2.1 in the module otherModule?  Perhaps with a Browserify transform?

Moving all my modules into funcA so functions would be scoped properly would be a huge headache of course so if there is a way around it that would be great.  I tried moving my require statements into funcA, and I also tried passing $ into funcB and both didn't work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You will probably want to `import $ from 'jQuery'` in all of those modules, then let browserify compile that dependency so that you can fill in `jQuery321` at runtime when calling your main module.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Bergi for the tip!  It led me in the right direction.  Now all versions of $ in modules are 3.2.1, and $ in the browser console is 1.8.1

Comments indicate new code:

```js
var jQuery321;    //add variable name for exporting

var otherModule = require('./funcB')

//now we set jQuery321 to the proper version of jQuery to export
if ((typeof jQuery === 'undefined') || (parseFloat(jQuery.fn.jquery) < 3.0)) {

  loadScript("https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js", function(){
      jQuery321 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
      funcA(jQuery321);
  });
  } else {
      jQuery321 = jQuery;   //added this line
      funcA(jQuery);
}

var funcA = function($){ 
    $('document').ready(function(){
    
      console.log('jquery in funcA: v' + $.fn.jquery)  
      otherModule.funcB();  
      funcC();  
      
    })
    
    function funcC(){
      console.log('jquery in funcC: v' + $.fn.jquery)
    }  
}

export { jQuery321 };   //export proper version of jQuery
```

```js
//code from otherModule --> funcB.js 

import { jQuery321 as $ } from '/myScript.js';  //add import statement

exports.funcB = function(){
  console.log("jQuery in funcB: v" + $.fn.jquery)
}

module.exports = exports;
```